# Embedding an Access *.accdb Database into a .NET application

Tags: .net, database, visual-studio-2010, ms-access, embedded-database

I want my users not to be able to see the MS Access *.accdb Database I am using. Therefore would I like to embed it into the assembly. How should I do this?

My guess is to modify the connection string.

The connection to the database has been automatically made with the import wizard. The connection string can be found in the file `Settings.Designer.vb` and has been written like this:

```
Global.System.Configuration.ApplicationScopedSettingAttribute(), _
Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute(), _
Global.System.Configuration.SpecialSettingAttribute(Global.System.Configuration.SpecialSetting.ConnectionString), _
Global.System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\MyDatabase.accdb;" & "Persist Security Info=True")
```

Is there a way I could change `Data Source=|DataDirectory|\MyDatabase.accdb` (last line, scroll right) to something else?

I found an article on [how embed resources](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319291/en-us), but they seem not to apply to a connection string. Furthermore, it seems that (at least in 2008), [to access an MS Access Database, it had to be taken out of its embedded state](http://www.codeproject.com/Messages/2684948/Re-Connection-String-to-an-Embedded-MS-Access-Data.aspx). This would make useless this embedding in my program.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I confirm: to try to embed a database into an assembly does not make sense if the purpose is to hide it.

As an assembly is a static structure, no bit can be changed in it. So something as dynamic as a database definitely has to be taken *out* of the assembly before it can be used.

In order my users not to see the database I am using, I opted for the solution to copy it into the `&AppData&` directory. Not very secure (despite the password protection) but at least not obvious.

Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14644532/1458491) to see how.