# Distribute database on end user machine

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, sqlite, ms-access, connection-string

I have a little desktop application using a `*.db3` database. When I run the application on other machine than mine, the database cannot be found: an absolute path is used.

Currently, in my `App.Config` file, I have

```
connectionStrings>
    add name="MyProject.My.MySettings.MyProjectSQLiteConnectionString"
            connectionString="data source=&quot;N:\Long path do my DB\MyDB.db3&quot;"
            providerName="System.Data.SQLite" />
/connectionStrings>
```

I would like to replace the data source with something like this (unfortunately not working)

```
data source =|DataDirectory|\MyDB.db3
```

How can I enter the application directory (relative path) in my connection string?

Comment: What about using some path like `%APPDATA%`? or let the user change this config from the preference screen of your app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with Steve B's comment and later finding this [article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/67c417e8-cf39-4ae2-928c-2b4f709b146d), I solved my problem doing the following:

1. On the user machine, the database is copied into the `%AppData%` directory.
2. The `|DataDirectory|` is dynamically changed between Debug and Release mode.

This allows not to change the connection string.

In the meantime, I opted for a MS Access *.accdb database, but here is my code anyway.

```
Private Sub Main_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

#If (Not Debug) Then

    pathMyAppData = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) & "\MyApp"

    '"DataDirectory" is used in the Connection String
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", pathMyAppData)


    'The application closes if no database is found
    If Not File.Exists(pathMyAppData & "\MyDB.accdb) Then
        MsgBox("Database not found. Program closes.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")
        Me.Close()
    End If

#End If
```